# Why do I get lifetime error when using a reference in a struct that is still valid?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm new to Rust, and I'm trying to learn more about lifetimes. I came across the following piece of code, which won't compile ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d13e1a16bbb55fb7d0c259b1c4269646)):

```rust
struct Person<'a, 'b> {
    name: &'a str,
    email: &'b str, 
}

fn main() {
    let my_name: String = String::from("John Doe");
    let me: Person;

    {
        let my_email: String = String::from("john@example.com");

        me = Person {
            name:  &my_name,
            email: &my_email,
        };
    }

    println!("My name is {}.", me.name);
}
```

Notice the use of two different lifetime parameters in the definition of `Person`.

Here is the compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: `my_email` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:20
   |
15 |             email: &my_email,
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
16 |         };
17 |     }
   |     - `my_email` dropped here while still borrowed
18 |
19 |     println!("My name is {}.", me.name);
   |                                ------- borrow later used here
```

The compiler complains about `my_email` not living long enough. However, I'm not using it, or any reference to it (`me.email`, for example). I'm rather trying to print `me.name`, which refers to `my_name`, and the lifetime of it won't end until the end of `main` function.

However, the following piece of code, which is a small modification of the code above, compiles and runs as intended ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf9b57455b1d3e71d77250210268db23)):

```rust
struct Person<'a, 'b> {
    name: &'a str,
    email: &'b str, 
}

fn main() {
    let my_name: String = String::from("John Doe");
    let name_ref: &str;

    let me: Person;
    {
        let my_email: String = String::from("john@example.com");

        me = Person {
            name:  &my_name,
            email: &my_email,
        };

        name_ref = me.name;
    }

    println!("My name is {}.", name_ref); // Prints "My name is John Doe."
}
```

I can't understand why the first piece of code doesn't work, despite everything looking fine. Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **are** using it. You are storing it in the struct.

As long as `me` exists, the `me.email` exists as well, regardless of whether you are accessing it or not. And according to [Rust's soundness rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html), a reference that exists has to always be outlived by the data it points to. A reference cannot be dangling.

The reason the second code works is because you do not access the `me` structure outside of the innermost context. `name_ref` no longer depends on `my_email`, and `me` no longer exists. So Rust is able to destroy `me` first and can then safely destroy `my_email`.

One subtle detail to understand here is that `name_ref` does **not** depend on `me`. Assigning a reference to a new variable (in this case, from `me.name` to `name_ref`) **copies** the reference. `name_ref` purely depends on `my_name`.

How does the compiler know that? By implicit lifetimes. The Rust compiler actually keeps a hidden lifetime annotation with every reference (at compile time only). So the Rust compiler understands that `name_ref` actually references `my_name` (or at least in a more abstract way that the lifetime of the thing `name_ref` points to has to match `my_name`).

---

`struct`s in Rust take over the lifetime of their members. So if you store a reference inside of the struct, *the entire struct* will depend on the referenced object's lifetime. You could say the struct derives its lifetime dependencies from its members. That's also what the compiler warning tells you: because you use `me` in general, this lifetime dependency has to be honored. It doesn't matter if you use the actual object.

You can see this already in its declaration:

```rust
struct Person<'a, 'b> {...}
```

The lifetime `'b`, in this case, captures the dependency to the `my_email` object, and the lifetime is attached to the entire `Person` object, not just its `email` member.

This can go even further:

```rust
struct Person<'a> {
    email: Option<&'a str>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut me: Person;
    {
        let my_email: String = String::from("john@example.com");

        me = Person {
            email: Some(&my_email),
        };

        me.email = None;
    }

    println!("My name is {:?}.", me.email);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `my_email` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:25
   |
11 |             email: Some(&my_email),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
15 |     }
   |     - `my_email` dropped here while still borrowed
16 |
17 |     println!("My name is {:?}.", me.email);
   |                                  -------- borrow later used here
```

Note that at the point where the inner context is left, `me.email` contains `None`, so the `me` object isn't even referencing `my_email` any more. Nonetheless, creating the object with `Person { email: Some(&my_email) }` burns this lifetime into the instantiated type of `me`. A lifetime behaves similar to a generic: it is burned into the type of the variable, and the type of the variable cannot change by mutating it.